# Xamarin Android binding class FooInvoker does not implement interface setter

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Android binding error that makes no sense!

The generated class stubs are:

```
[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/scichart/drawing/common/IRenderSurface", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
internal class IRenderSurfaceInvoker : global::Java.Lang.Object, IRenderSurface


[Register ("com/scichart/drawing/common/IRenderSurface", "", "Com.Scichart.Drawing.Common.IRenderSurfaceInvoker")]
public partial interface IRenderSurface : global::Com.Scichart.Core.Framework.IInvalidatableElement, global::Com.Scichart.Core.Framework.IView { } 

// Metadata.xml XPath interface reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.core.framework']/interface[@name='IView']"
[Register ("com/scichart/core/framework/IView", "", "Com.Scichart.Core.Framework.IViewInvoker")]
public partial interface IView : global::Com.Scichart.Core.Framework.IContextProvider, global::Com.Scichart.Core.Framework.IHitTestable 
{

    int Visibility 
    {
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.core.framework']/interface[@name='IView']/method[@name='getVisibility' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("getVisibility", "()I", "GetGetVisibilityHandler:Com.Scichart.Core.Framework.IViewInvoker, SciChart.Android.Core")] get;
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.core.framework']/interface[@name='IView']/method[@name='setVisibility' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='int']]"
        [Register ("setVisibility", "(I)V", "GetSetVisibility_IHandler:Com.Scichart.Core.Framework.IViewInvoker, SciChart.Android.Core")] set;
    }
}
```

What's happening is IView.Visibility (which has get, set) is conflicting with a base class Android.View.Visibility. I've worked around the conflict in additions folder but there is this IRenderSurfaceInvoker class which is generated, and not partial, and isn't implementing the IView interface properly.

[image]

Normally I'd ignore the property in metadata.xml and create it manually in a partial class, but that isn't possible as IRenderSurfaceInvoker is not partial.

What is a FooInvoker anyway??!

Any ideas? :)

**EDIT: UPDATE**

After Sven-Michael Stube's answer below, I have this partial solution:

```
<!-- In EnumMethods.xml -->
<mapping jni-interface="com/scichart/core/framework/IView">
    <method jni-name="getVisibility" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Android.Views.ViewStates" />
    <method jni-name="setVisibility" parameter="visibility" clr-enum-type="Android.Views.ViewStates" />
</mapping>
```

But this results in the IView interface being generated as follows:

```
    global::Android.Views.ViewStates Visibility {
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.core.framework']/interface[@name='IView']/method[@name='getVisibility' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("getVisibility", "()I", "GetGetVisibilityHandler:Com.Scichart.Core.Framework.IViewInvoker, SciChart.Android.Core")] get;
    }
```

and the warning output

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.core.framework']/interface[@name='IView']‌​/method[@name='setVisibility']/parameter[@name='visibility']"/> matched no nodes
```

In other words, the EnumMethods.xml declaration above deletes the setter as it cannot find a match.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to workaround your `View` vs `IView` problem. You should override the return value of the getter and the parameter of the setter to be `Android.Views.ViewStates` in **EnumMethods.xml**. This **may** solve your problem if you do it consistently.

```
<mapping jni-interface="com/scichart/core/framework/IView">
    <method jni-name="getVisibility" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Android.Views.ViewStates" />
    <method jni-name="setVisibility" parameter="p0" clr-enum-type="Android.Views.ViewStates" />
</mapping>
```

Comment: One small problem. jni-class should be jni-interface otherwise both nodes cannot be found. But even then it replaces the getVisbility and deletes the setVisibility with the warning <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.core.framework']/interface[@name='IView']/method[@name='setVisibility']/parameter[@name='visibility']"/> matched no nodes Any ideas?

Comment: is the parameter called `visibility? This was just a guess.

Comment: In java, yes it is. C# still can't find it. I have however named it to p0 and it randomly worked :0

Comment: I edited your answer to fix + accepted. Thanks for help!